# Convert DateTime parameter for SQL statement from ORACLE DB in to the accepted format (query folding for Incremental Refresh)

Tags: sql, oracle, powerbi, datetime-format

I am trying to set up incremental refresh in POWER BI, because my dataset contains more than 3 million rows (each refresh take now too long).

Since the table comes from an Oracle DB, my query is not folded, then I tried with the function `View.NativeQuery`, with the following result:

[image: .]

But when I add more step, in this case set the parameter `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd` by filtering, this are not included in the query folding, the bottom is not active

[image: .]

I have also tried by adding to the function  `null,[EnableFolding= true]`, but the command is invalid.

Then I though I could include the `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd` parameters in the query statement (`View.NativeQuery`), so that the filtering is included in the query folding (with a supported DB, the result of the query folding should result the same)

Since the parameter is in DateTime format (eg. 01/09/2023 00:00:00) and the date format from the db is 'DD-MON-YY' (eg. 01-SEP-23), how could I write it in this query statement?

```
= Value.NativeQuery(TABLE, "select * from Oracle_view where Oracle_view.yr=2024 and Oracle_view.el1>='3000' and Oracle_view.el1<='99999'")
```

By adding a parameter at beginning as:

```
stdate=RangeStart
```

and by adding to the statement " and `Oracle_view.valdate>= to_char('"&stdate&"','DD-MON-YY') "` I get back an error (& can't be applied to Text and DateTime).

Can someone help me with this? My need is to convert the DateTime parameter in an accepted format for the query statement in Oracle.
I would like at least to produce a correct SQL statement that works with a date parameter, and then verify if this query folding allows to me to apply the incremental refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately query folding with incremental refresh is not available. What is the use case of using query folding?

This [link](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/it-ch/blog/incremental-refresh-query-folding/#:%7E:text=The%20Power%20BI%20service%20partitions,is%20called%20%E2%80%9Cquery%20folding%E2%80%9D.) will speak more about query folding and incremental refresh.

This [link](https://learnsql.com/cookbook/how-to-format-a-date-in-oracle/) will help you to format the datetime column as the desired format in oracle sql.